# HP Envy backlight key (f5) not working? How to turn on the backlight?

Tags: keyboard, hp-envy

I have an HP model 13-j002dx which is an HP Envy with a detachable keyboard. I have Windows 10 Home installed on it.

The refresh button f5 works when I do fn+f5. When I press f5 to turn on the backlight for the keyboard, nothing happens. I've tried the usual solutions: press the space bar + f12, update the keyboard drivers, and nothing works.

I once took it to the Geek Squad. They charged $40 for a simple less-than-in-a-minute repair. The guy said it had something to do with the drivers, but nothing more - he was vague about it. How can I get the backlight key to work, or is there any other way to turn on the backlight?

Comment: Do you have the installation disc that come with the laptop? Usually there are driver installers. Or visit HP support website, and find all drivers needed.

Comment: This [Driver Identifier](https://www.driveridentifier.com/) has helped me finding many drivers needed on many computers. Let's hope it can help you too!